# SDL_CreateRenderer returning nullptr

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm just starting to learn SDL, and I'm following one of the tutorials I've found, I wrote a simpl code to render a bmp pic to the screen but its not working, the the problem is that the SDL_CreateRenderer is not created (the pointer keeps pointing to nullptr)

```
dint main (int argc, char* atgs[]) {
int a = 0;
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1) {
    std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
a = 1;
SDL_Window *win = nullptr;
win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
if (win = nullptr) {
    std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

SDL_Renderer *ren = nullptr;
ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
if (ren == nullptr) {
    std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

SDL_Surface *bmp = nullptr;
std::cout << "hello";
bmp = SDL_LoadBMP("c:/hello.bmp");
if (bmp == nullptr) {
    std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

SDL_Texture *tex = nullptr;
tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, bmp);
SDL_FreeSurface(bmp);

SDL_RenderClear(ren);
SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tex, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
SDL_Delay(2000);

SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
SDL_DestroyWindow(win);

SDL_Quit();


return 0;
```

}

ren keeps being null, any idea, why?

I though it was because of the computer but I didn't found any problems online, I'm using win 8.1, intel hd4000 graphic card and visual studio 2012.

thx :)

Comment: Check the condition in the `if` statement when you create the window, that's an assignment there.

Comment: haha, thx man, I've been looking all over the internet for this, -feeling dumb :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the SDL_Window you perform a check to see if it is null. This is a good thing to do but in your if statement, instead of using an equals comparison operator `==` you used an assignment operator `=`

```
win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
if (win = nullptr) {  // This should be if (win == nullptr) {
    std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

This allocates null to the win variable and causes `SDL_CreateRenderer` to return null since that requires a valid SDL_Window